# Как заполнить поле номер телефона в заявке с помощью Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, form

Задача автоматически заполнять форму заявки ниже с помощью Python.

[image: форма заявки]

Никак не могу сообразить, как заполнять форму для ввода телефона. Фамилия, имя и почта рандомно заполняются из файла txt. ИНН рандомно генерируется в необходимом диапазоне. Надо помочь решить задачу с заполнением номера телефона из файла txt.

```
import time
import random
from selenium import webdriver


browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:\Program Files\geckodriver-v0.30.0\geckodriver.exe')
browser.get("http://nrpgov.ru/")

xpath = '/html/body/form/div[4]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/a'
browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()

surname_xpath = '/html/body/form/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/input'
lastname = open('surnames.txt', encoding='utf-8').readlines()
browser.find_element_by_xpath(surname_xpath).send_keys(random.choice(lastname))

name_xpath = '/html/body/form/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/input'
name = open('boys.txt', encoding='utf-8').readlines()
browser.find_element_by_xpath(name_xpath).send_keys(random.choice(name))

inn_xpath = '/html/body/form/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/input'
inn_random = random.randint(1000000000, 9999999999)
browser.find_element_by_xpath(inn_xpath).send_keys(inn_random)

number_xpath = '/html/body/form/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/input'
browser.find_element_by_xpath(number_xpath).send_keys('9293454545')

email_xpath = '/html/body/form/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/input'
mails = open('mails.txt', encoding='utf-8').readlines()
browser.find_element_by_xpath(email_xpath).send_keys(random.choice(mails))

send_xpath = '/html/body/form/div[7]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/span'
browser.find_element_by_xpath(send_xpath).click()
```

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/442034/

Comment: Спасибо, с captcha я разберусь... сейчас больше интересует ввод номера телефона

Comment: Вы пробовали и у вас не получается вести телефон?

Comment: Да, никак не получается ввести цифры. Не знаю с чем это связано, по идее всё правильно написано. Другие же формы заполняются...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный ответ был получен на [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) от пользователя @JustOscarJ

```
number_xpath = '/html/body/form/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/input'
browser.find_element_by_xpath(number_xpath).click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath(number_xpath).send_keys('9293454545')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тема закрыта.